# Use of "The Same"

Tags: pronouns

I came across many sentences , in few *the same* is correct but in other its use was incorrect. Although going through many sites, didn't understand the difference.

> The police started the investigation but couldn't complete the same .

Here there is no error as per exam answer key.

> When you have gone through my notes, give the same to me.

In this, use of the same is wrong.

Whats the difference. How to use 'the same' in correct way.

Comment: Where  did  you  find  the  sentences? who  said  that  one  is  correct  and  the  other  is  wrong?

Comment: @Englishmonger These questions are from SSC CGL exam taken by Indian government

Comment: The use of *the same* is grammatical in both sentences. And it's more common that a previous comment is suggesting. I wouldn't say I hear—or read—it *frequently*, but it's certainly used and not at all obsolete. (1) *I'm going to study now. I suggest you do the same.* (2) *I ate a hamburger for dinner that night. I ate the same (thing) the following night too.*

Comment: As a BritEnglish speaker I agree with your answers: both are correct but very rarely used. However in IndEnglish (definitely not quite the same!) 'the same' is used in this sense much more frequently, but I'm not a native IndEnglish speaker so couldn't comment on the specific rules for it.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Your examples are correct and very common usage. But OP's constructions are very unidiomatic. I can't see why anyone would use OP's exact sentence construction. I can't think of a situation where anyone would say *"I started eating a cheese burger but couldn't finish the same"* instead of *"I started eating a cheese burger but couldn't finish it"*.

Comment: @AIQ but in Indian English, especially in rather formal situations (signs, officialese, etc.), some forms are used that are essentially obsolete or extremely formal in Western flavours of English.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other comments and the differences in Canadian English between the two sentences, I think I can answer your question.

> The police started the investigation but couldn't complete the same.

In Canadian English, this sentence would become the following:

> The police started the investigation but couldn't complete **it**.

"it" is used because the object of the sentence, "investigation", is a singular noun. Compare this to the next sentence in Canadian English:

> When you have gone through my notes, give **them** to me.

"them" is used because the object is a plural noun, "notes".

Going back to your original sentences, I think "the same" is correct in the first sentence because in Indian English "the same" is used to substitute for "it" and to refer to a singular object/noun. The second sentence is incorrect because using "the same" would mean using it to substitute for "them" and to refer to a plural object/noun.

I'm not a native Indian English speaker, so it's hard to tell how correct my answer is with only two examples to apply it to, but hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**In legal language and in administrative law (government) language**, you do see **same** or **the same** used like that regardless of the variety of English. I only give four country examples below. I think those are enough.

My example:
- They did not complete the investigation of (the) same. [same would have to be defined earlier in the text]

It is considered very formal and is used in most varieties of formal, legal or administrative English.

It refers to some matter or subject previously mentioned in a text.

Example from a court case cited online:

US:

> "Thereupon, the witnesses were duly sworn and the Court then heard
>   testimony from the various witnesses for the State and the defendant,
>   and **at the conclusion of same** and after due consideration, the
>   Court does hereby sustain the Motion to have the juvenile jurisdiction
>   of this matter waived and the proceeding transferred to the criminal
>   jurisdiction of this Court and to have the defendant tried as an adult
>   rather than as a juvenile and gave its finding of fact and conclusion
>   of law concerning same...."

[same](https://law.justia.com/cases/west-virginia/supreme-court/1983/15698-4.html)

In the paragraph above, the word **same** refers to the **testimony of all the witnesses**.

Here's one from South Africa:
[same](http://www.saflii.org/za/cases/ZANCHC/2018/81.html)

It is used six times in the text.

> 4)    That the first respondent be ordered to pay the costs of this
>   application; alternatively, the first and second respondent, jointly
>   and severally, be ordered to pay the costs of this application in the
>   event the second respondent opposes **same.**

And here is one from Northern Ireland.

> [...] relating to disputes over the title to Folio 2974 and the
>   litigation over many years now in respect **of same.** [Northern
>   Ireland - same](https://judiciaryni.uk/sites/judiciary/files/decisions/Ferris%20%28Patricia%29%20v%20Patricia%20Montgomery.pdf)

I recommend not using it in normal circumstances.

Also, for me, this: *When you have gone through my notes, give the same to me.*
is not really great.

*When you have gone through my notes, give them back to me.*

And this: *The police started the investigation but couldn't complete the same*. could conceivably be found in a not-so-well-written police report.

The formal nature of **same** does not go well with **couldn't**. But police officers are not known for being good writers.

Comment: Thanks but why you replaced the same in second sentence. When you have gone through my notes give them to me. Is the same incorrectly used here.

Comment: @Pradeep It should be clear that "same" or "the same" would not be used in a non-legal context. I stated that clearly.